# Is it possible to do incremental data load (SSIS) in multiple table of a database with lot of relationship?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, cdc

I want to do incremental data load say for 50 tables with lots of relationship is there in those table. And I want to do it through CDC of SSIS. Can anyone help me out abut this. We have tested it successfully for 1 table but for 50 table we need to design 50 CDC package. Is any alternative approach is there?

Comment: Create a parent package and execute the child packages in a loop might help. pls check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895287.aspx

Comment: Thanks @bmsqldev.. Still we have to create 50 packages, is there any option to provide parametrised table name in the cdc package? Till now I haven't find so.

Comment: Check out [BIML](https://www.varigence.com/biml). You can use it to generate SSIS packages.

Comment: No, there is no option to parameterize the destination table in a single SSIS dataflow.